# Having trouble implementing Yahoo BOSS v2 with OAuth in .net/C#

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, yahoo-api

I've been trying to create a simple search page using the Yahoo BOSS v2 api, but cant get OAuth to work properly. I have all the keys etc, and downloaded a C# class for OAuth at http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs , but I keep getting errors.

We've tried the following:

a javascript function builds a yahoo boss query string and then leads to
PageMethods.getYahoo(query string, responseFunction);

Here's the code behind

```
[WebMethod]  
public static string getYahoo(string url)  
{  
    String result;  
    OAuthBase oauth = new OAuthBase();  
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://mysite.com");  
    string a, qstring = "";  
    string signature = oauth.GenerateSignature(uri, "-my consumer key-", "-my
    secret-", out a, out qstring);  
    url = url.Replace("{oauth}", qstring + "oauth_signature=" + signature);  
    WebResponse objResponse;  
    WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);  
    objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();  
    using (StreamReader sr =
    new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))  
    {  
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();   
        sr.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

here is my GenerateSignature method in oAuthBase class:

```
public string GenerateSignature(Uri url, string consumerKey, string
    consumerSecret, out string normalizedUrl, out string
    normalizedRequestParameters)
{  
    normalizedUrl = null;  
    normalizedRequestParameters = null;  

    string signatureBase = GenerateSignatureBase(url, consumerKey,null
    ,null,null,GenerateTimeStamp(),GenerateNonce(), HMACSHA1SignatureType, out
    normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);  

    HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1();  
    hmacsha1.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}&{1}",
    UrlEncode(consumerSecret), ""));  

    return GenerateSignatureUsingHash(signatureBase, hmacsha1);  

}
```

But we keep getting the error:

```
Message: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'getYahoo' failed
with the following error: System.Net.WebException-- The remote server returned
an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Line: 6934
Char: 21
Code: 0
```

I hope someone here can help...!

Comment: are you on the ysearchboss@yahoogroups.com e-mail list?  a few days ago they post a working example (not checked by me) it is c#. do you want it posted here?

Comment: Yes Luis, please post it here or post a link to it here!  Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

You could use my [.NET library](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/) or looking into the source code of it for using BOSS v2.
An example of using the lib you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/sampleYahooManagedSearchAPIWebSearchDownload).